# SQLNCLI10 Error when executing stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-job

I have a job running in one of my server and which uses a linked server  and the linked server changed as part of upgrade and now my job fails everyday.
I am getting the following error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "linked server" returned message "No transaction is active.".
>
> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "linked server" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

And if I directly execute the procedure in linked server from my server then, for the first time it shows this error and for the second time it execute with out any problem.

My new linked server is 2012 version and the other one is 2008 R2 version

Please let me know your thoughts?

Thanks,
Sivajith

Comment: Is Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator installed and enabled on both servers? not sure if it is still needed but it was needed in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQL Server 2008 **R2** but in 2008 for this issue was released a fix, that is available [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954950)